# Ojdbc14.jar in glassfish - can't find it

Tags: java, linux, glassfish, suse

I have Suse linux and i,ve installed Glassfish 3.1.1 but i cant create pools with

```
resource type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
```

the following error is:

```
Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource Please      enter code here`check the server.log for more details.
```

I have ojdbc14.jar in **glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/Ext** and **glassfish/lib**

i dont know more to do,thanks!

Comment: Don't use `ojdbc14.jar` it's outdated (it's intended for Java **1.4**!). Use `ojdbc5.jar` if you are still using Java5, or `ojdbc6.jar` for Java6 and Java7

Comment: I think jdbc drivers belong in `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib`.

Answer (score 2):

Your location for putting this jar as a global resource is wrong. You need to remove this jar from `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/Ext` and `glassfish/lib` and add it only into `glassfish/domains/domain1/lib` - this is the place in glassfish for libraries like `JDBC` to be found in the global classpath.

Comment: this fix worked for ojdbc6.jar in glassfish 4.1 for netbeans 8.1, java 7

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the plugin Glassfih in eclipse, then you should put the jar in Glassfish which is inside the eclipse.
Or you remove the Glassfish server and add a new server and point to the folder you downloaded glassfish, place the jar in the following section within
/ glassfish3/glassfish/lib.